# My boot time is almost 1 minute?

Tags: boot

My laptop is HP Pavilion with AMD 2.2Ghz processor and 8 GB of RAM and my booting time is unbelievable 50 secs ! Around 50 secs before Ubuntu hits login screen. Isn't it little too much for my laptop's specs considering Windows 10 booted up within 10 secs.

What kind of log you need me to post here to help you recognize what's bugging my Ubuntu while booting ?

OK here it is:

```
      7.442s apparmor.service
      6.130s dev-mapper-ubuntu\x2d\x2dvg\x2droot.device
      2.602s ModemManager.service
      2.569s accounts-daemon.service
      2.197s lvm2-monitor.service
      2.053s NetworkManager.service
      1.998s thermald.service
      1.876s networking.service
      1.789s grub-common.service
      1.719s polkitd.service
      1.556s plymouth-start.service
      1.480s systemd-udevd.service
      1.476s lightdm.service
      1.473s keyboard-setup.service
      1.296s console-setup.service
      1.203s systemd-logind.service
      1.116s gpu-manager.service
      1.104s apport.service
      1.082s ufw.service
      1.077s systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-BB99\x2d8489.service
       998ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
       970ms systemd-modules-load.service
       896ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
```

Comment: Start with the output of `systemd-analyze blame`.

Comment: Windows 10 has Fast Boot, which basically just hibernates the OS. 50 seconds isn't long at all. My i7, 7200rpm HDD, 8GB RAM takes about the same to boot Ubuntu, maybe a little less.

Comment: So I suppose your laptop is even better and takes the same time to get it ready to use ? 50 secs is too much. Why average time is 15 secs which is absolutely reasonable ? Will post the log requested once I get home. Cheers.

Comment: @MarkAlexa Like Jos said, please post output of `systemd-analyze blame`.

Comment: @MarkAlexa why is 50 seconds too much? You must never have used Windows 7 or XP.

Comment: @MarkAlexa average time is most certainly not 15 seconds! Less than a minute is pretty darned fast. As others have said, you are probably comparing it to Windows which isn't actually booting, only coming back from hibernation. Try [actually shutting down](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/force-full-shutdown-fully-reinitialize-windows-8) Windows and then see how long it takes to boot.

Comment: Aha .... yeah I guess I'm bit spoilt by Windows 10 booting. I had used W10 for over a year so I got used to having it ready to go straight away .... so this is normal ??? Wow ....

Comment: Just wanna say thank you all for your thoughts about this !

Comment: Just read article about this app called E4RAT which makes Linux start up fast like Enterprise from Star Trek. Will give it a go ...